# media player errors on eclipse phonegap android emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I have a simple app playing different sounds when you touch different buttons.

It is this line repeated 22 times:

```
<div class=btn7><a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src="android_asset/www/a.mp3" ></audio>א</a></div>
```

It works fine on the browser but the emulated app gives me these errors:

on load, 30 or 40 errors of

```
error (1, -2147483648)
```

When try to play a track - error

```
Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=1 
Error (-38,0)
```

If try to play a track for a 2nd time:

```
Attempt to attempt to call getduration without a valid mediaplayer
```

How do I find my problem and fix it?

Comment: show some code for better answers

Comment: My question is what the errors mean.  Its in the wrong state.  What does that mean?  How will the meandering code that produced the errors help? I didnt declare the media, but not sure exactly how to do that, but maybe there is a different problem?

Comment: it is so hard to tell since we don't even know what code you are using. Are you using an audio tag or the Media class in PhoneGap. More details result in better answers.